# storing object references in map C++

Tags: c++, reference, hashmap

I'm new to C++ and trying to figure out a good way to store object references in map or unordered_map.

I've tried map<Key&, Value&> and  map<reference_wrapper<Key>, reference_wrapper<Value>> and I can make then work eventually but it looks very ugly and I'm sure bug-ridden.

I know I can use pointers instead but I don't want to allocate memory as I'll have to clean up after.

Anyone knows of a good and clean way to achieve this?

Comment: How about smart pointers?

Comment: What is the reason you want to use references? Especially for the key? What is the real and actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: Another point about using references or (non-smart) pointers, they need to be valid all throughout the lifetime of the map. You can not, for example, have a reference to a local variable in a function (including non-reference arguments) and then return from that function and expect the reference to work.

Comment: I always thought using references in a map is illegal

Comment: @MauriceRandomNumber: It is, but the `reference_wrapper` version does work.

Comment: Dijikstra algorithm. Vertices are stored in a graph while I need to use a separate structure for book-keeping. So need a way to associate a vertex to one of these structures and vice versa

Comment: I guess now that I think about it, there's probably not enough space on the stack for those Memo struct anyways so I will need to allocate memory then free later. This question is still curious to me though so I'll keep it open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a reference, then you have a "thing" that the reference refers to. Consequently, you can just as easily store a pointer to the same "thing" without the need to allocate any additional memory. Pointers don't *require* dynamic allocation.

That being said, storing a smart pointer would be simplest and cleanest unless you have real, measurable performance concerns. I worry about unclear object lifetimes and dangling references, in your design.

Comment: Good point. I'm trying to implement Dijikstra algorithm, and need a way to associate a reference to an object stored elsewhere with a local object that I'm creating, and vice versa

Comment: @TV1989: Does this not sound like a good job for `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr`?

Comment: Yes it sure does